# How to use a parameter to display a default image?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report that I generate on my webserver. The report contains and image which I pass as a parameter which all works fine on report generation.

But I want also to be able to use this image in my report design in Jaspersoft Studio and wonder how I can do this. Can it be loaded as the `defaultValueExpression` for example something like below?

```
<parameter name="MyLogo" class="java.lang.Object">
    <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
    <defaultValueExpression>path/to/file here?</defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display an image from location you will need to indicated **absolute path** in `imageExpression`

For this reason I often use 2 parameter, 1 for the base path (location of images) and 1 for the image to display (name of image) on both you can indicated `defaultValueExpression` and if you need to change them pass your value through the parameter map. Naturally you can use only one parameter containing the complete absolute path to image.

**Example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="image" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="61ee899d-277b-4efa-9306-c325b54ac022">
    <parameter name="IMAGE_PATH" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\pette\\Desktop\\tmp\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="THE_IMAGE" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["theboss.jpeg"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <title>
        <band height="118" splitType="Stretch">
            <image scaleImage="RealSize">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="139" height="95" uuid="f5f1c323-b120-48ed-98a5-478a5b907429"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{IMAGE_PATH} + $P{THE_IMAGE}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

**Output**

[image: Result]